# Failed to build iOS app on Codemagic when I have two different Firebase project

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

I use codemagic for my Flutter app. I have no Issue when building Android File. but it always failed whenever I build iOS.

I have two different Firebase project, one project is used for production environment and the other one is for development like this

[image]

so I will have two different `GoogleService-Info.plist`. I have two different schemes (Flavors) called production and development. I save the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file inside the config folder like this on my Xcode

[image]

I have pre-build script on my Xcode, that is used to decide which `GoogleService-Info.plist` that should be used based on the scheme/flavor used (Production or development) like this:

[image]

here is the script from my Xcode:

```
environment="default"

# Regex to extract the scheme name from the Build Configuration
# We have named our Build Configurations as Debug-dev, Debug-prod etc.
# Here, dev and prod are the scheme names. This kind of naming is required by Flutter for flavors to work.
# We are using the $CONFIGURATION variable available in the XCode build environment to extract
# the environment (or flavor)
# For eg.
# If CONFIGURATION="Debug-prod", then environment will get set to "prod".
if [[ $CONFIGURATION =~ -([^-]*)$ ]]; then
environment=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi

echo $environment

# Name and path of the resource we're copying
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST=GoogleService-Info.plist
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE=${PROJECT_DIR}/config/${environment}/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}

# Make sure GoogleService-Info.plist exists
echo "Looking for ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} in ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE}"
if [ ! -f $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE ]
then
echo "No GoogleService-Info.plist found. Please ensure it's in the proper directory."
exit 1
fi

# Get a reference to the destination location for the GoogleService-Info.plist
# This is the default location where Firebase init code expects to find GoogleServices-Info.plist file
PLIST_DESTINATION=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app
echo "Will copy ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} to final destination: ${PLIST_DESTINATION}"

# Copy over the prod GoogleService-Info.plist for Release builds
cp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE}" "${PLIST_DESTINATION}"
```

I believe I need to add/modify that script when I build my app on Codemagic because I always have this error message. but I don't know how. please help!

> "No GoogleService-Info.plist found. Please ensure it's in the proper
> directory."

Comment: * fix {PROJECT_DIR} to ${SRCROOT} * you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323031/what-the-different-between-srcroot-and-project-dir)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75045383/failed-to-build-ios-app-on-codemagic-when-i-have-two-different-firebase-project), you have to create the file before Xcode starts building the project.

In the pipeline you can run a script that will create an empty file before the build starts: `touch ios/Runner/GoogleServices-Info.plist`.

In your local development, the first time you build, either create that empty file or run the build twice (the copy script is actually successful the first time).

Comment: It's not working to.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have two configs to build app, it's dev & prod and i have two configs in Codemagic to. Below are two steps that helped me build successfully with Codemagic.

1. My `copy script in Build Phases`

```bash
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug-prod" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release-prod" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]; then
cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/config/prod/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist"
elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug-dev" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release-dev" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug" ]; then
cp -r "${PROJECT_DIR}/config/dev/GoogleService-Info.plist" "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist"
fi
```

2. In Codemagic config `Post-clone script`

```bash
cp -r "ios/config/dev/GoogleService-Info.plist" "ios/GoogleService-Info.plist"
```